# How to align divs horizontally in different screens like desktop,mobiles , etc?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display divs horizontally i.e "a checkbox along with some content[div]".

Code :

```css
.manager_feed_div_block {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.appstatus {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.manager_feed_div {
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 218px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="manager_feed_div_block">
    <div class="appstatus">
      <input type="checkbox" name="app_status" />
    </div>
    <div class="manager_feed_div">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="appstatus">
      <input type="checkbox" name="app_status" />
    </div>
    <div class="manager_feed_div">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="appstatus">
      <input type="checkbox" name="app_status" />
    </div>
    <div class="manager_feed_div">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="appstatus">
      <input type="checkbox" name="app_status" />
    </div>
    <div class="manager_feed_div">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="appstatus">
      <input type="checkbox" name="app_status" />
    </div>
    <div class="manager_feed_div">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="appstatus">
      <input type="checkbox" name="app_status" />
    </div>
    <div class="manager_feed_div">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="appstatus">
      <input type="checkbox" name="app_status" />
    </div>
    <div class="manager_feed_div">
      some content
    </div>
    <div class="appstatus">
      <input type="checkbox" name="app_status" />
    </div>
    <div class="manager_feed_div">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Output:

[image: Output of what I am tried]

Here I faced two problems

1.I want "the checkbox and its corresponding div " should come as a group . But when you notice the output I got , "At the end of the first line , the checkbox is separated from its corresponding div".

2.It is not responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Layout varies from editor to editor.So,try changing this part.

```
 <style>  
      .manager_feed_div_block{ content:"";display:table;clear:both;}
      .appstatus{float:left;margin-top:40px;margin-right: 10px;}
      .manager_feed_div{background:#fff; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px ; border-radius: 4px;  float:left; border:1px solid #dbdbdb; padding:5px; margin-right:20px; margin-bottom:20px; width:218px; text-align:left; position:relative; margin-top:20px;}
    </style>
```

In my editor at size 1135 x 672 I am getting this :- [image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this with CSS-Grid:

```css
.manager_feed_div_block {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 200px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.manager_feed_div_block .container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="manager_feed_div_block">
  <div class='container'>
    <div class="appstatus">
      <input type="checkbox" name="app_status" />
    </div>
    <div class="manager_feed_div">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class="appstatus">
      <input type="checkbox" name="app_status" />
    </div>
    <div class="manager_feed_div">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class="appstatus">
      <input type="checkbox" name="app_status" />
    </div>
    <div class="manager_feed_div">
      some content, some longer content, to see how this breaks.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class="appstatus">
      <input type="checkbox" name="app_status" />
    </div>
    <div class="manager_feed_div">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class="appstatus">
      <input type="checkbox" name="app_status" />
    </div>
    <div class="manager_feed_div">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class="appstatus">
      <input type="checkbox" name="app_status" />
    </div>
    <div class="manager_feed_div">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class="appstatus">
      <input type="checkbox" name="app_status" />
    </div>
    <div class="manager_feed_div">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class="appstatus">
      <input type="checkbox" name="app_status" />
    </div>
    <div class="manager_feed_div">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Quick Explanation**

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 200px);
```

will fit as many 200px containers onto the screen as possible (see Fullscreen snippet and try resize to see the effect), while

```
grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
```

will prevent breaking the checkbox and the content into new lines. `grid-gap:10px;` will define the spacing between single containers on the one hand and your textcontent and checkbox on the other.

Pretty easy.

A quick introduction into CSS-Grid can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp